# difference between java and dotnet versions of solr

Tags: c#, java, solr

does any one knows how behind is the c# version of Solr from its java version? does any one suggest we use c# based instead of java based?

best

Comment: There isn't any c# version of solr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are referring to a C# client library for Solr. In fact, you don't have to worry if Solr is written in Java, there are a lot of different client libraries you can use to communicate with Solr without using java. You just need to install Solr on a Java servlet container like Tomcat, provide your xml configuration, basically the `schema.xml` and `solrconfig.xml` files. After that you can start using your favourite client library, written in C# for example, to communicate with Solr.